# $paged do not work in wordpress frontpage

Tags: wordpress, templates, frontpage

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
query_posts($args);?>
```

I used this code in WP page template, then published a page with this template, then set this page as static homepage, then I find paged always equals 1.
when I click page 2, I still get same content as page 1, although url is correct ,such as `/page/2/`

Answer (score 1):

i find the answer myself.
just use

```
get_query_var('page')
```

instead,it will work.